# How to convert symbol list response into json arraylist from fixer.io? (How to convert JSON key value pairs into JSON Array)

Tags: android, json, arraylist, gson, retrofit

I want to show list of currencies with `currencyName` and `currencyCode`,
but getting response like

```
{
  "success": true,
  "symbols": {
    "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
    "AFN": "Afghan Afghani"
  }
}
```

and how can I convert this into,

```
{
  "success": true,
  "symbols": [{
      "code": "AED",
      "name": "United Arab Emirates Dirham"
    },
    {
      "code": "AFN",
      "name": "Afghan Afghani"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to show list in Android application.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method :

```
JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
        resultObject.put("success",true);
        JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray();


            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(yourJsonString);

            JSONObject jsymbol= jsonObject.getJSONObject("symbols");
            Iterator<String> iter = jsymbol.keys(); //This should be the iterator you want.
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                String key = iter.next();
                String value = (String) jsymbol.get(key);

                JSONObject jsonObject1=new JSONObject();
                jsonObject1.put("code",key);
                jsonObject1.put("name",value);
                jsonArray.put(jsonObject1);

            }

            resultObject.put("symbols",jsonArray);//This will give you result you want


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```